# Uninstalling global npm package leaves an error in npm list

Tags: npm

I'm having some issues uninstalling some of my global npm packages, in that they don't appear to be fully removing.

As an example, I've been trying to remove the beta Angular CLI package (as this package was renamed for its 1.0.0 release). Running `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` appears to work, however when I then run `npm list -g --depth=0` the package appears to remain in the list, now with an error:

`error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/package.json`

It appears as though the package has not been fully removed - I'm not sure if this can be fixed using `npm prune`, or simply by going in and manually deleting any files that may be left over.

I've not had any success googling around the issue, however this could be because I'm not entirely sure what to search for, as evidenced by my not-so-eloquently worded title for this question.

If anyone has any thoughts, I'd be very grateful to hear them!